# VPC SSL/HTTPS environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, https, amazon-vpc

I have the following VPC setup with AWS Elastic Beanstalk:

1. Web App Public Load Balancer pointed to by my domain (proxied through cloudflare) with EC2 instances in private subnet.
2. Private internal API Load Balancer with inbound access granted to EC2 instances above via Security Group
3. Database within the private subnet, accessible by EC2 instances behind the API Load Balancer.

I would like to enable end to end HTTPS, AWS has good documentation here (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-endtoend.html).

I have followed this, albeit with my free Cloudflare domain certs. This seemed ok until I get the following error: 'SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN' when my web app tries to connect to the internal API via https://internal-aweseb-dns.amazonaws.com (DNS for internal API Load Balancer).

Questions

1. Is this the correct way get end to end HTTPS?; and
2. How do I resolve the above error? (returned by Node JS)

Thanks

Comment: Where did you deploy the self-signed SSL certificate?

Comment: @Marcin the cert is my domain cert (not self-signed), it is deployed onto the load balancer and the EC2 instances behind it as directed by the AWS docs. It may be more of Node JS issue not recognizing the cert nternally perhaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I came to this conclusion: I don't need end to end HTTPS when my instances are in a private subnet because:-

1. Once HTTPS is terminated at the Load Balancer, the internal requests are over HTTP but are not over the public internet. They requests cannot be seen by anyone outside the AWS network.
2. The data I am transmitting is not overly sensitive (just emails and user preferences) so there is no Compliance/Regulatory reason to enforce end to end HTTPS in a private network.
3. There is a small performance hit when using HTTPS as an SSL handshake must occur, which is an overhead.
4. I have additional security via Security Groups, only allowing internal traffic originating from the Load Balancer.

There are many suggestions that would guide you to configure your application to ignore the certificate when connecting via HTTPS... but that defeats the whole point of HTTPS (secure encrypted connection). You may as well just HTTP instead of doing this.

After much research and discussion with AWS, I think using HTTP over an internal network is secure enough for 99% of use cases and is pretty standard with a lot of setups and so unless you actually need end-to-end encryption for your use case, I would advise doing this instead.

Hope this helps.